# Python/ regex: delete text before the 4rd delimeter

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have this string

```
/foo/foo1/foo2/something
```

How would I delete everything before the 4th `/` and keep the something bit.

some strings are also

```
/foo/foo1/foo2/something/something/
```

hence why everything before the 4th `/`

thanks

Comment: show your efforts

Comment: i dont really know regex hence the question

Comment: could be there more than 4 slashes? is it about getting the last section?

Comment: sorry should have written the question better hopefully the edit makes it more understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`re.subn()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re#re.subn) function:

```
import re

s = '/foo/foo1/foo2/something/something/'
result = re.subn(r'[^/]*/', '', s, 4)[0]

print(result)
```

The output:

```
something/something/
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your example string looks like a file path, I would use `os.path.basename`

```
from os.path import basename
filename = basename("/foo/foo1/foo2/hello")
```

Comment: Its not a filepath, it still worked however i do have some strings with texts after a 5th '/' so just need to delete everything before the 4th '/'